# Postfix - Display both envelope from and email from in logs

Tags: linux, centos, office365, postfix-mta

Postfix logs the `envelope from` in the email logs. When I check Office 365 message trace the `email from` differs from Postfix logs.

I have customized Postfix to log both the subject and attachments which does help me in matching the message flow in both Postfix and Office 365.

Is there a way for Postfix to log both the `email from` and `envelope from`?